# Replacing DVD-ROM with SSD on HP Envy 15t

Tags: ssd, hp-envy, m.2

Does anyone know if HP Envy 15t have m.2 port? And how can I replace the DVD-ROM with SSD on it?

Also what size of SSD does it support?

Comment: Normally you replace HDD with SSD, they are the same size for specifically this reason. I'd be surprised if you managed to fit an SSD instead of the DVD-ROM.

Comment: If I replace the HDD with SSD, and want to insert and connect the HDD (for storing files only, the OS will be on SSD) using a caddy in the optical drive bay, what size of caddy would I need? And does Envy 15 has m.2 port for higher connection speed? I can't find anything about that in the manual.